# how to listen of angular template driven form changes

Tags: javascript, angular

in my form:

```
<form>
   <label class="form-check-label">
     <input [(ngModel)]="options.o1" name="o1"
            type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" >
     Option 1
   </label>
   <label class="form-check-label">
     <input [(ngModel)]="options.o2" name="o2"
            type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" >
     Option 2
   </label>
</form>
```

I want to be informed whenever one of the two checkboxes is changed, not by adding an event handler to each of the checkboxes but by adding an event handler to the form, in reality there are much more fields in the form.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can get hold of `NgForm` directive like:

**html**

```html
<form #form="ngForm">
   ...
</form>
```

**ts**

```typescript
@ViewChild('form') ngForm: NgForm;
```

for Angular 9 and above you should use `static: true` option:

```typescript
@ViewChild('opportunityForm', { static: true }) ngForm: NgForm;
```

and then listen `valueChanges` on `NgForm.form`

**ts**

```typescript
ngOnInit() {
  this.formChangesSubscription = this.ngForm.form.valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
    console.log(x);
  })
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.formChangesSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

**[ng-run demo](https://ng-run.com/edit/CGoUiw88N7OmI7x0YmHJ)**

Comment: btw, did you forget to unsubscribe on destroy?

Comment: and the initialization is also logged before any user does changes. Maybe I have to add a timout.

Comment: well, in the end I used a ReactiveForm

Comment: In my case I had to use property `read`: `@ViewChild('inputField', { read: NgControl }) inputField: NgControl;`

Comment: `@ViewChild('form', { static: true }) ngForm: NgForm;` since angular 8

Answer (score 8):

I used accepted answer and base on that I create a demo version for whom concern.

TS file

```
export class AppComponent {
  
  options: any;
  formChangesSubscription: any;
  @ViewChild('form') ngForm: NgForm;

  updated: any;

  constructor() {
    this.options = { o1: true, o2: false }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formChangesSubscription = this.ngForm.form.valueChanges.subscribe(form => {
      console.log(form);
      this.updated = form;
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.formChangesSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

HTML file

```
<form #form="ngForm">
  <label class="form-label">
     <input [(ngModel)]="options.name" name="name"
            type="text" class="form-input" >
     
   </label>
   <label class="form-check-label">
     <input [(ngModel)]="options.o1" name="o1"
            type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" >
     Option 1
   </label>
   <label class="form-check-label">
     <input [(ngModel)]="options.o2" name="o2"
            type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" >
     Option 2
   </label>
</form>

<label>{{updated?.o1}}</label>
<label>{{updated?.o2}}</label>
<label>{{updated?.name}}</label>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-template-form?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

You should use reactive form as @Remify mentioned and after that you can try this:

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
     console.log('form changed');
});
```

To use reactive form check the angular documentation:

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: As I know, do NOT forget to unsubscribe from this subscription since it is a way for memory leak. Do that on ngOnDestroy(). Such a subscription is different from the http one where you don't need to unsubcribe.

Answer (score -8):

I have a bad news for you : Use a reactive form. They are exactly what you describe.

Comment: I agree that reactive form are better. But for op this means more work.

Comment: A reactive form is used beneath `NgForm`. So you just need to grab its `form` then you can do whatever a reactive form application can. (yurzui got it right)

Comment: Either you use a reference to the template variable #form using @ViewChild() inside your component OR use Reactive forms. Thus, the answer is wrong. It depends on your requirements and how much control over a form you need.