# Is there a way to get Form Value without using NgForm/FormGroup?

Tags: angular

I have a form tag which wraps a component which contains different input fields.

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
    <component-with-input-fields></component-with-input-fields>
</form>
{{myForm.value | json}}
```

Each input fields have ngModel directive attached but when i tried accessing `myForm.value` it just outputs `{}`.

Here is a sample of markup of `component-with-input-fields`:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let attr of attributes">
    <input type="text" name="attr{{attr.attribute_id}}" ngModel>
</ng-container>
```

NOTE that the input fields and its name are dynamic.

Is there another way of getting the form values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a reusable FormGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696761/create-a-reusable-formgroup)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660515/how-to-listen-of-angular-template-driven-form-changes

Comment: @Vikas Far from a solution, in that question form control directives are present in the template.

Comment: can you show us your input fields html?

Comment: How and where are you trying to access form values?