# Listen for template driven form changes in Angular 10

Tags: angular, angular-template-form

I have a template driven form in my angular 10 app that I am trying to listen for changes to so that I can show an 'changed, please submit updates' message to the user.

HTML

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()" class="form-horizontal" #opportunityForm="ngForm">
...
```

opportunity.component.ts

```
export class OpportunityComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('opportunityForm') ngForm: NgForm;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    ...
    this.formChangesSubscription = this.ngForm.form.valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
      console.log(x);
    })
```

but it get an error that:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined
```

because the ngForm is not initialised. This is a similar question to: [how to listen of angular template driven form changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660515/how-to-listen-of-angular-template-driven-form-changes) which has a running answer at https://ng-run.com/edit/CGoUiw88N7OmI7x0YmHJ which has the same problem.

How can I grab the form and make sure it exists before I listen for changes? I am using Angular 10.2.0

Not sure if this makes a difference but the whole page is wrapped in a

```
<div *ngIf="loaded">
```

which is set after an api call in the ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dataService.getOpportunity(this.id)
        .subscribe(data => {
           ...  //fills the data up
        }, error => console.error(error),
        () => {
            console.log(this.loaded);
            console.log(this.ngForm);
        });
```

puts out true (for loaded) and undefined (for this.ngForm).

****UPDATE*****

So it does look like it's because I have the entire form only loaded after the data comes bac. Because it's not on the page then @ViewChild can hook onto it. I put my *ngIf on a div inside the form and it is working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `static: true` option to `@ViewChild` decorator:

```
@ViewChild('opportunityForm', { static: true }) ngForm: NgForm;
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/CGoUiw88N7OmI7x0YmHJ)**

otherwise you have to move subscription to `ngAfterViewInit` hook

Comment: I added updated ng-run example. If it is still not working for you then you have some wrapper with `*ngIf` and can use setter for ViewChild like here https://ng-run.com/edit/O2yXbflec2xvl6lkPQJ2

Comment: thanks. all the demos I set up in stackblitz all work as expected. It must be something to do with my configuration