# How to check if any value was changed in an editable Object without using FormGroup?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-changedetection

I am having nested objects with multiple properties. I have created an input field on the UI for every property and value is changed by using [(ngModel)]. I want to implement a functionality where if any value in the object is changed I should be able to detect it and enable the reset option to show initial values again.

I have tried exploring this and the majority of answers were related to form controls only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660515/how-to-listen-of-angular-template-driven-form-changes

Comment: yes partially, I just need to know if it is touched or dirty. I tried it but now it throws an error cannot read the form of undefined. Not able to figure whats happening

Comment: Please update the question with the code and the error text

Answer (score 1):

if you bind with two-way binding to data you will not be able to hold old record. You can write a fn to compare to objects if you bind with [ngModel].Here is pseudo.

```
in .ts
value = {}



onValueChange(data:any){
const changedData = getChangedData(this.value, data);
}
in .html

<input [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="onValueChange($event)">
}
```

Comment: don't forget equal value to $event!: in function onValueChange:`this.value=data`, in .html `(ngModelChange)=value=$event`. IF you only want use a variable you can also use `<input [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="change=true;value=$event">`

Comment: This works fine but I have a nested Object with multiple input fields. It will be difficult to track all the changes using ngModelChange.

Comment: if you hold them in a single object, there is no other way to hold the record as far as i know. If you're distrubiting the nested object to a child component and if you have an access to it on implicit level, you can easily track it. But in your question that's the only way i can think